# What does this SQL-Server syntax do? How to convert into Teiid SQL version?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, jboss, teiid

This is a part of sql syntax,

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), HIADDITIONAL, 2))
-- HIADDITIONAL is varchar
```

What is the syntax supposed to do?

**Update**

The sql is [sql-server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms187928.aspx) syntax. How to convert the syntax into [teiid](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/TEIID/Type+Conversion+Functions) version?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms187928.aspx, You could just look it up.

Comment: converting `HIADDITIONAL` to `varbinary(max)` first and then convert it (the result) to `varchar(max)` , that is the process of that syntax..